# Password recovery of a ComponentACE Absolute Database

Tags: database, delphi, password-recovery

I was given a pretty old desktop application written probably in Delphi C++ Builder with an embedded AbsoluteDB.

I need to create a new version using either Swing or Flex/Air, but before I do that I need to check the exact schema of the DB.

Unfortunately, the DB was password protected. The programmer who wrote this app left the company long time ago.

Is there anyway to recover this password?

Comment: Have you tried `1234` :-? No, seriously, my suggest is to contact [`vendor`](http://www.componentace.com/company/contact_us.php).

Comment: Brute force attack might take a long time. You could try hooking the DLL and its functions, and seeing if you can see the data being passed in to the DLL where it opens the database or passes in the password, which might not be ascii text, it might be a binary private key. Let's assume you have the source code to the delphi app? The password could be inside the source code right?

Comment: Reading between the lines, I presume you have also lost track of the source code of the App, haven't you ?

Comment: Absolute Database uses very strong encryption including Rijndael 256 among others. Your best bet is to circumvent password recovery so as to get the DB schema and/or pump the Data: This is possible if you have the source code of the App (complete or partial) in working order or the App allow plugin extension (bpl) provided the TABSDatabase instance can be found by iterating `Forms.Application` component childrens (recursively).

Comment: ok, and what about his documentations? or the team ? (must be the password somewhere with the team)

Comment: @Warren P: A running App using **Absolute Database** stores the password (string) in a the first field of a record along with the CryptoAlgorith (Byte): In plain/not encrypted. Is there a way to "inspect" that?

Comment: @TLama: That's only applicable for registred user and provided there is no  restrictions regarding the support duration and/or version where support applies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Naive Brute force attack**

It's a non sense to use the stock `TABSDatabase` to attempt a brute force attack since:

- Internal Hash methods and Encryption methods use a unique buffer as input and output (passed as reference). Every iteration required the same input content to be processed (no caching for reuse for sake of CPU time sparing).
- Every false password raises an Exception and SEH add another penalty layer (time complexity).
- I suspect other by-design features (counter-measures against brute force attack).

---

**Getting rid of every superflous load**

I came up with this **working** bare Delphi class in my attempt:

```
type
  TABSDBHack = class
  private
    FFilename: TFileName;

    // 2 relevant contiguous headers of an Absolute Database file
    FDBHeader: array [0..SIZEOFDBHEADER-1];
    FCryptoHeader: array [0..SIZEOFCRYPTOHEADER-1];

    // Mirror of the ControlBlock record from CryptoHeader
    FControlBlock: array [0..SIZEOFCONTROLBLOCK-1] of Byte; 
    //
    function GetEncrypted: Boolean;
    function GetFileName: TFileName;
    function GetPageSize: Word;
    function GetPageCountInExtent: Word;
    function GetCryptoAlgorithm: Byte;
  protected
    // Retrieving Data from stream into FDBHeader and FCryptoHeader
    procedure ReadStream(F: TStream);

    // Mainly FillChar(..., ...,#0) of the corresponding record
    procedure ClearDBHeader;
    procedure ClearCryptoHeader;
    procedure ClearControlBlock;

    // Probe the existence of 'ABS0LUTEDATABASE' as file signature
    function CheckABSSignature: Boolean;

    // Compute the CRC of FControlBlock record
    function CRC32: Cardinal;

    // Decrypt the persisted Control Block into FControlBlock
    function InternalDecryptBuffer(const APassword: string):Boolean;
  public
    procedure Clear;

    // Wrapping a ReadStream using a local TFileStream
    procedure LoadFromFile(Filename: TFileName);

    // Return True if the decrypted Control Block correspond to original plain one.
    // Otherwise stated: The persisted CRC (in the Crypto Header) is equal to 
    // the value returned by the function CRC32
    function CheckPassword(const APassword: string): Boolean;

    property FileName: TFileName read GetFileName;

    // Sample of plain Data peristed that can be retrieved
    property PageSize: Word read GetPageSize;
    property PageCountInExtent: Word read GetPageCountInExtent;
    property Encrypted: Boolean read GetEncrypted;
    property CryptoAlgorithm: Byte read GetCryptoAlgorithm;
  end;
```

I retrieved relevant data directly from file and probe a given password.

*Disclaimer*:

I used a Personnal Edition of Absolute Database version 6.0.7 to develop it.

The class defintion was cleaned of any reference to any type definitions from the DCUs distributed and I am not entitled to distribute a binary based on it.

As of know, it strongly depends on the DCU's distribution, mostly for the hash and decryption method. With time and more knowledge of the Absolute Database's internals writing a clean room implementation of its encryption engine should be feasible: It seems that it's based on the *Delphi Encryption Compendium* a freeware by Hagen Reddmann.

---

**Other Direction to explore**

- Brute forcing to recover the plain Control Block can be considered as SIZEOFCONTROLBLOCK is only equal to 256.
- Given a pair of plain/encrypted Control Block, recovering the internal representation of the Key is possible using too brute force but watch out: 128/192/256 for AES/Rijndael for instance!.
- RipeMD (128 as well as 256), a well known one-way function, is used internally to initialize Key: I am afraid that it's not reasonably feasible to recover a string given its hash!
- Most of the Crypto Algorithm (The recent ones at least) underwent thourough test under public scrutinity prior to their adoption as standard: Simply put they are strong, very strong I mean.

---

**Conclusion**

Yes! It is possible to recover the password under some provisions.

When playing around with TABSDBHack, the key to succes is to find a way to reduce the search space (password is of string Type): It's easy as pie, especially for **weak** password. I emphasize, it works.

The Guys from Component Ace are smart and did well their job (devising the cryptosystem among other thing): You can rely on Absolute Database, I strongly advocate it.

Comment: +1 for example code on a bruteforce hack.

Comment: @menjaraz Many thanks for taking the time to experiment and reply. I agreen with you that using TABSDatabase for a brute-force is a nonsense, if I am not mistaken, the idea is to apply a (guess) password to a plain DB file and compare it with the encrypted DB file, right? But I think I am still missing a few pieces from reading your response: 1). what are DBHeader, CryptoHeader and ControlBlock? 2). how to get the crypto algorithm used? 3). How to apply the password "manually"?

Comment: 1) DBHeader, CryptoHeader are records used in memory to hold the first 2 relevant headers of an Absolute Database file for the sake of decrypting. ControlBlock is a record mirroring a field within CryptoHeader, used as an output buffer for the modified CR32 and InternalDecryptBuffer to preserve its counterpart (input buffer) from being overriden.

Comment: 2) The Crypto Algorithm is persisted as a Byte in the CryptoHeader but you must first probe from the DBHeader to ascertain that the file is encrypted.

Comment: 3) Pass an arbitrary string password to the method `TABSDBHack.CheckPassword(const APassword: string): Boolean;` and it will tell if it is OK. You can wrap it within another more capable class wrapping a brute force attack and/or dictionnary attack services for instance.

Comment: @menjaraz - Although I don't konw Pascal (I am a C++/Java programmer), the code you posted seems to be just the class (or type) declaration. As I am not familiar with AbsoluteDB, could you kindly post the other implementation code?

Comment: @Tong Wang: As you noticed in my post it is questionable to distribute the actual code as it strongly depends on the DCUs files of Component Ace and that also doesn't entitle me to distribute a binary based on it. I'd rather suggest you to buy an affordable  [Single Developer with source code](http://www.componentace.com/order/) license ($199). You will have at your fingertips all needed uptodate information. I wish I could have too those source codes.

Comment: @Tong Wang: Another alternative. I don't have any idea of what is at stake regarding the migration project you intend to undertake  but you can post your password recovery as a project on [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.co.uk/): It will certainly receive attention from a bunch of well versed crackers willing to make money there.

Comment: @menjaraz: Ok, I got you. Thank you very much for all the help.